# Delay in manifest changes or not seeing add-in at all

Tags: outlook-web-addins

We are seeing an odd behavior where we update a manifest in production (basically remove the old one, add the new one) through EAC, however it takes more than an hour to take effect.  My understanding is that the admin-defined manifests are stored in a particular System Mailbox, so I am confused why there should be a lengthy delay.  Is there way to troubleshoot this, and (2 for 1) is there a general way to troubleshoot an Outlook App not showing up in, say, Outlook 2013.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue in outlook web application or desktop clients (windows or mac) or mobile ?

Comment: I've seen the delay in Outlook (Windows) desktop which I use more often.  On a separate note, we've had troubles trying to get add-ins to show up on some user's Outlook (Windows) desktop, and on Mac.  When it does show up, we don't have a clear understanding of why.  Sometimes we suspect certificate issues is the cause.  Is there a magic log that will shed some light onto how Outlook discovers and loads/doesn't load the manifest file, or settings that affect this?

Comment: We are working through the Outlook Mac issues (ability to see the add-in) which seem related to DNS resolution, and self-signed certificates.  Directed the requests through a HTTPS proxy to see what was going on.

Comment: This is the expected behavior, it can take upto 4 hours to get the latest manifest if deployed via EAC. Please have a look at comment made in this post via Sreeram https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Centralized-Deployment-for-Outlook-add-ins-will-now-be-generally/ba-p/161164

Comment: I wanted to mention to everyone that it is important to update the version inside of the manifest file, whenever a change is made to the manifest.  In addition, if resources are updated, like icons, images, etc., will likely need to change the path of these in the manifest.  We discovered Outlook's file cache of the manifest and resources and surmised that in some cases Outlook may not have pulled down the manifest because the version number was the same, and definitely the resources (e.g. images, icons) were not refreshed if the URL to the resource was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior, it can take upto 4 hours to get the latest manifest if deployed via EAC. Please have a look at comment made in this post via Sreeram https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Outlook-Blog/Centralized-Deployment-for-Outlook-add-ins-will-now-be-generally/ba-p/161164